# Make a java library executable

Tags: java, executable-jar, api-design

I have developped a java library with part of it being a server application and the other part being a client API to connect to the server.
I'm trying to build a jar that may be executed to launch the server but which also keeps my API classes exposed.

I used maven shade to achieve my goal but could not find how to configure it to dispatch my packages both in jar root and in BOOT-INF directory.
Not sure this is the correct final layout anyway...
I use Spring and Spring-boot for the server application part.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>${application.group}.SimProxy</Main-Class>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>${dependency.spring-test.group}:spring-test</exclude>
                                <exclude>${dependency.hamcrest-library.group}:hamcrest-library</exclude>
                                <exclude>${dependency.junit.group}:junit</exclude>
                                <exclude>${dependency.vertx.group}:vertx-core</exclude>
                                <exclude>${dependency.vertx-junit5.group}:vertx-junit5</exclude>
                                <exclude>${dependency.mockito-core.group}:mockito-core</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

As I say, I'm not sure of the final jar layout, but my other compile scoped library packages are visible at the root of the jar.
I would expect the API packages to be also set at the root of the jar for the client API to be used in other projects.
Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should never distribute a library .jar which is also an executable. It's best practice to have it either being purely a library, offering the functionality to start your server (so that the consuming app can start the server), or a standalone executable that isn't ment to be imported.

I think you're best off to just split the .jars or let the consuming app start the server.

Comment: I would like to avoid splitting the jar in 2. The thing is the server si supposed to be running on a different machine than the app using the client API...  No possible way to expose even part of the code ?

Comment: @keuluu could you elaborate a bit more on what your server application does, what your API part does, and why you want to keep them in the same jar? :)

Comment: The server application provides cached data for multiple clients. It may be launched locally on the client machine, but may also in some other situations be available for clients on the network. A connection agent is the API part I want client applications to use to connect to the server. I expect there should be many client apps developped by various teams in a business context where I would like everything to be packed in the same "library".